# SQL: number of elements that appear at least twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like:

```
ID    DATE
01    20.06.13
01    21.06.13
02    13.04.13
03    12.05.13
04    17.05.13
04    19.06.13
```

I need to query so that I have the total amount of distinct ID which have two or more entry in the DATE field. For example in the example table only 01 and 04 have at least two entries so the result of my query should be 2.

Comment: Why isn't 3 in your expected result set?  Or are you saying that the result set should be 01, and 04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your requirement is the *total count* of unique duplicates, not to list the duplicate items themselves, here is the query to do that:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
   (
      SELECT ID
      FROM dbo.YourTable
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING Count(*) >= 2
   ) X
;
```

You could also use some kind of `JOIN` (including a subquery, correlated or not) but that will be far less efficient than the aggregate above.

Comment: Agreed. A count and a set are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: You could lose the DISTINCT.  It's not buying you anything.

Comment: And why not predicate with HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1?

Comment: @MikeCheel In this case that would be identical. But if you could have `NULL` IDs, then they would be excluded from your method. The GROUP BY  expression is what you're really want to count. Think about the scenario where you have two columns expressing uniqueness, such as `ID, Phase` or somesuch... you can't do `Count(ID, Phase)`, so suddenly your habit breaks down. So speaking solely from my own experience as a SQL professional, in general I would advise using `Count(*)` over specifying a column name. If you do have to change the `GROUP BY` expression, you don't have to do it in two palces.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Select id
from table
group by id
having count(id) > 1
```

Comment: I always prefer `>= 2` than `> ` because to me it flips the logic. The concept "where there isn't only one" is not the one I'm holding in my mind, I'm thinking "where there are duplicates (read: TWO or more)".

Comment: I think you are splitting hairs.  To me "where there are more than 1" means duplicates.  Like "where ID is plural".

Comment: It's just a comment--take it or leave it. They're absolutely the same to the engine. I tend to pay more attention to conceptual streamlining than many people care to. And perhaps you just think differently. That's okay, but I got my 2 cents in. :)

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for your interest.  Have a great day!

Comment: P.S. that was supposed to say "prefer `>=2` over `> 1`"

Comment: @Blam Hounding would be a -1, which did not happen. But just to prove I'm the sport you wonder if I'm not, +1.

Comment: :)  Thanks ya'll.  And yet another question where it seems the answerers care more than the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
select totalDuplicatedIds = count(*) 
from (
    select id 
    from table 
    group by id 
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```